# Is there any use to salmon heads and spines?

Tags: culinary-uses, stock, salmon

The fishmonger gave me a whole salmon rationed, and included the head and spine. I threw the head and spine away, but was wondering whether there is any culinary use for it.

Normally in a fish stock, I use white fish, not blue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I agree that you can get some good meat from the head and could use it to flavour Bouillabaisse, i wouldn't however use it for stock as oily fish can lead to a cloudy fatty stock rather than the clearer and more flavoursome fish stock that can be derived from the off cuts and bones from white fish.

Comment: I've seen a recipe for a 'strong fish stock' that uses salmon. I've also seen a warning against this type of stock as being too strong. So, bouillabaisse could be an option, next time around.

Answer (score 4):

Lots of good meat on the head (e.g. right on the cheeks), don't throw it away!

Answer (score 3):

I use salmon bones in stock all of the time.  It's delicious!

Comment: I've always wondered if there were any kinds of fish that didn't make good fish stock?

Answer (score 3):

The heads contain a lot of natural collagen and meat, so they are perfect for making [head cheese](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_cheese).  Here is [a good recipe for king salmon heads](http://blog.ideasinfood.com/ideas_in_food/2011/05/the-beauty-of-headcheese.html).  Here is [a picture of the result of that recipe](http://blog.ideasinfood.com/ideas_in_food/2011/05/king-salmon-and-herbs.html).

Comment: One word: nice (15 chars or more)

Answer (score 1):

If you actually like gnawing on bones (like my parents), you can sprinkle some seasoned salt and bake/smoke them... and then gnaw on them...

They also prepare the head in various ways like steaming in rice wine with a bunch of scallions and ginger or the aforementioned stocks.  This also depends on whether you like picking meat off.